# ¿Como puedo meter un json object de los items de los productos en un textarea?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy utilizando Angular y el Plugin de ng-cart para el carrito de compra; el problema es que todo trabaja bien pero requiero que los items se pongan en un textarea para guardar en la bd.

El json que envia es:

```
{  
   "shipping":null,
   "tax":0,
   "taxRate":null,
   "subTotal":1318.52,
   "totalCost":1318.52,
   "items":[  
      {  
         "id":"4",
         "name":"Clasico Panini",
         "price":80,
         "quantity":13,
         "data":"2",
         "total":1040
      },
      {  
         "id":"2",
         "name":"Mixiote",
         "price":69.63,
         "quantity":4,
         "data":"2",
         "total":278.52
      }
   ]
}
```

Tengo actualmente un bucle for que me me imprime en consola los items sin problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando lo quiero imprimir en el textarea, parece que nada mas pone el ultimo item nada mas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe varios metodos pero obtengo el mismo resultado, y si mando directamente el `ngCart.getItems();` en el textarea obtengo `[object][object]`.

la url del plugin como referencia es:  ngcart.snapjay.com/docs

Comment: veo las respuestas y no digo que esten mal, pero quisiera saber para que necesitas el resultado en un textarea? sospecho que puedes mejorar bastante tu codigo si nos revelas que intentas lograr.

Comment: Quetal, lo que requiero es mandar en un formulario de pago los datos de los productos para que se suban a la tabla de pedidos, olvide decir que esta es una aplicación en phonegap con onsen ui. 
Ahorita lo que hace es solamente mandarme el ultimo item y no logro hacer que salga todo en el textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que el contenido de un textarea es sólo **un string** y tu tienes **un arreglo** de items por lo que tienes que unir todo usando el método `join`.

```
var productos = ngCart.getItems();
var i;
var results = [];
for (i= 0; i< productos.lenght; i++) {
    results.push('(' + productos[i]._quantity + 'x) Ordenes de: ' + 
                 productos[i]._name + ' :-: Precio unit: $' + 
                 productos[i]._price);
}
$scope.productos = results.join('\r\n');
```

Te dejo un demo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var productos = [{
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Clasico Panini",
      "price": 80,
      "quantity": 13,
      "data": "2",
      "total": 1040
    }, {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Mixiote",
      "price": 69.63,
      "quantity": 4,
      "data": "2",
      "total": 278.52
    }];
    var i;
    var results = [];
    for (i = 0; i < productos.length; i++) {
      results.push('(' + productos[i].quantity + 'x) Ordenes de: ' + productos[i].name + ' :-: Precio unit: $' + productos[i].price);
    }
    // Unelos usando saltos de línea para que queden unos debajo de los otros 
    $scope.productos = results.join('\r\n');
  })
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <textarea ng-model="productos"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Es correcto ya con ese arroja los items, gracias fue de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si colocas tu `$scope.productos = productos` dentro del `if`. Es decir, algo como el siguiente código:

```
for(...){
var producto = ...
$scope.productos = producto;
}
```

Quedo a tu espera.

Comment: Hola, ya meti el codigo asi y me sigue imprimiendo el ultimo item del carrito, habrá alguna manera en la cual se concatenen o alguna otra forma en la cual puedan salir no importa si no es un textarea, pero que se    pueda enviar cuando se de clic en el form y atraparlos en el servidor php mediante $_POST['productos']?

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que declaras `producto` dentro del bucle, por lo que en cada iteración `producto` **está guardando el elemento actual** y al acabar el bucle `producto` tiene el valor del último producto.

Lo que debes hacer es declarar `producto` fuera del bucle y en cada iteración concatenar tu representación string del objeto actual. De esta manera:

```
let producto = '';
for(let key in productos) {
    let actual = productos[key];
    producto += /* aquí creas el string de 'actual' */;
}

// solo para ejemplo, asumiendo un ng-model="areaProductos"
$scope.areaProductos = producto;
```

O también (como lo tienes):

```
$scope.areaProductos += '\n' + producto;
```